# Python: Memory issues: Criteria based combination

Tags: python, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have two lists and wish to generate a combination with the following criteria:

```
a = [1,7,12,50,51,52,57,59,60,61,67,96,59,58] 
b = [1,2,3,...200]

combination_a = [(p,q,r) for p in a for q in a for r in a]

combination_b = [(p,q,r) for p in b for q in b for r in b
                          if (p,q,r) not in combination_a]
print (combination_b)
```

How should I sort out memory issues with the program when handling large quantities of data and how should I get the output in excel?

```
import xlsxwriter workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Sample.xlsx', {'constant_memory': True}) 
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet() 

row = 0 

for row, group in enumerate (combo): 
  for col in range(3): 
    worksheet.write (row, col, group[col]) 

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Perhaps I miss something obvious, but isn't `combination_b` here always empty? It looks as if your `combination_b` should pick from the `b` list, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out corrected the code.

Comment: What is your use case for this?  As you've posted this code, you're stuck with holding all the triples in memory at once.  At the least, you could print the `b` triples individually, instead of making the full list all at once.

Comment: Also, if you are running out of memory, you are going to quickly encounter time complexity issues with `if (p, q, r) not in combination_a` since list membership tests are O(N)

Comment: @Prune I can print them individually in 2 different excel/csv files and then eliminate the duplicates? will Pandas help?

Comment: Again, that depends on the use case.  Pandas and CSV are a good match in general.

Answer (score 1):

a couple of optimisations.   first would be to store the smaller set in memory, something like:

```
combination_a = set(itertools.product(a, repeat=3))
for triple in itertools.product(b, repeat=3):
  if triple not in combination_a:
    print(triple)
```

otherwise, if you expect them both to be large you could avoid materialising the combinations via:

```
set_a = set(a)
for triple in itertools.product(b, repeat=3):
  if not all((t in set_a) for t in triple):
    print(triple)
```

then again, if `combination_a` doesn't fit in memory, you're going to have quite a problem on your hands.  iterating through that many items will mean total runtime will be astronomical

I'd suggest saving to CSV rather than MS Excel format.  There will be more than a million combinations which I think is beyond what Excel can handle?

writing in a loop is just a matter of:

```
import csv
with open('combinations_b.csv', 'w') as fd:
  out = csv.writer(fd)
  out.writerow(['a', 'b', 'c'])
  for triple in itertools.product(b, repeat=3):
    if triple not in combination_a:
      out.writerow(triple)
```

Answer (score 0):

This prints the triples singly, but the generator aspect gets it going quickly.

```
for triple in itertools.product(b, repeat=3):
    if triple not in itertools.product(a, repeat=3):
        print(triple)
```

---

**after OP update** ...

You can simply iterate through the generator:

```
for group in (triple for triple in itertools.product(b, repeat=3)
                      if triple not in itertools.product(a, repeat=3)):
    worksheet.writerow(group)
```

Comment: Thanks. Would this be helpful in generating the output in excel.                                                     
     import xlsxwriter
     workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Sample.xlsx', {'constant_memory': True})
     worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
     row = 0

     for row, group in enumerate (combo):
        for col in range(3):
        worksheet.write (row, col, group[col])

      workbook.close()

Comment: Code in comments is generally hard to read.  If you have a closely-related question, please edit it into this one (above).  If it's a only a follow-on, then please post a separate question.

Comment: `pandas` makes outputting to excel very easy.  otherwise I tend to write output to a CSV file which is easier and Excel also understands

Comment: @SamMason agreed but the issue is to eliminate values in df.combination_a from df.combination_b. Leaving everything in memory would again be problematic and throw an error. What's the workaround?

Comment: @Prune thanks for pointing it out have edited the question to reflect the code.